# SLD GeoServer COPY of styled labels from QGIS -with a created centroid - every label moved manually with X and Y on different places

Tags: qgis, geoserver, postgresql, sld, xml

In QGIS both in line, point and polygon type layers (for rivers, settlements, lakes..) I created labels for the objects - I created a field X and Y (Decimal Number), so that I define their location (look at picture) - manually. Basically I move every label separately from one another, and that label has it's specific coordinates. This is 2 years work now, so the new QGIS easy-fast option for manually moving labels was not yet created.

Now the question is this:

I invested a lot time now and I can not find a solution, inside or outside GeoServer documentation - I use SLD style export for all of the layers in GeoServer, that I have no problems styling. **However, I can not find a way to style the labels as such different positions, that they are visualized for every specific location with X and Y in GeoServer.** So I can not get the same result that I have in QGIS - in GeoServer.
I manage to use all of the other SLD styles - so that they are offset from the point in many different ways, but every single label is offest the same way as the others.

**Here are 2 SLD examples *for point type* that is exported from QGIS where I use this manual placement of labels.** .
1 Is the basic one, pure export from QGIS. But it won't load, because of map units. So >>2>> fixed one>>
2 Is modiffied with a line or two,so that it works - because of map units and projection.

And in the end, I show you a picture: How all 3 labels in GeoServer are on the right.

1 ORIGINAL ONE

```
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>LabelsTest</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>LabelsTest</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Cities</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Cities</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>code</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>1001</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PointSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/metre">
            <se:Graphic>
              <se:Mark>
                <se:WellKnownName>circle</se:WellKnownName>
                <se:Fill>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ffffff</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Fill>
                <se:Stroke>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Stroke>
              </se:Mark>
              <se:Size>4999.1999999999998181</se:Size>
            </se:Graphic>
          </se:PointSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Capital</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Capital</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>national_capital</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PointSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/metre">
            <se:Graphic>
              <se:Mark>
                <se:WellKnownName>circle</se:WellKnownName>
                <se:Fill>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ea3600</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Fill>
                <se:Stroke>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Stroke>
              </se:Mark>
              <se:Size>7000</se:Size>
            </se:Graphic>
          </se:PointSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>city</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:TextSymbolizer>
            <se:Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>name_old</ogc:PropertyName>
            </se:Label>
            <se:Font>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">Oranienbaum</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">10000</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Font>
            <se:LabelPlacement>
              <se:PointPlacement>
                <se:AnchorPoint>
                  <se:AnchorPointX>0</se:AnchorPointX>
                  <se:AnchorPointY>0.5</se:AnchorPointY>
                </se:AnchorPoint>
                <se:Displacement>
                  <se:DisplacementX>3555</se:DisplacementX>
                  <se:DisplacementY>0</se:DisplacementY>
                </se:Displacement>
              </se:PointPlacement>
            </se:LabelPlacement>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:VendorOption name="conflictResolution">false</se:VendorOption>
          </se:TextSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>national_capital</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:TextSymbolizer>
            <se:Label>
              <ogc:Function name="strToUpperCase">
                <ogc:PropertyName>name_old</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:Function>
            </se:Label>
            <se:Font>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">Oranienbaum</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">12000</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Font>
            <se:LabelPlacement>
              <se:PointPlacement>
                <se:AnchorPoint>
                  <se:AnchorPointX>0</se:AnchorPointX>
                  <se:AnchorPointY>0.5</se:AnchorPointY>
                </se:AnchorPoint>
              </se:PointPlacement>
            </se:LabelPlacement>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:VendorOption name="underlineText">true</se:VendorOption>
            <se:VendorOption name="conflictResolution">false</se:VendorOption>
          </se:TextSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

2 CHANGED ONE so it loads (of map units)

```
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>LabelsTest</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>LabelsTest</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Cities</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Cities</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>code</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>1001</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PointSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/metre">
            <se:Graphic>
              <se:Mark>
                <se:WellKnownName>circle</se:WellKnownName>
                <se:Fill>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ffffff</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Fill>
                <se:Stroke>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Stroke>
              </se:Mark>
              <se:Size>4999.1999999999998181</se:Size>
            </se:Graphic>
          </se:PointSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Capital</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Capital</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>national_capital</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PointSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/metre">
            <se:Graphic>
              <se:Mark>
                <se:WellKnownName>circle</se:WellKnownName>
                <se:Fill>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ea3600</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Fill>
                <se:Stroke>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Stroke>
              </se:Mark>
              <se:Size>7000</se:Size>
            </se:Graphic>
          </se:PointSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>city</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:TextSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/metre">
            <se:Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>name_old</ogc:PropertyName>
            </se:Label>
            <se:Font>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">Oranienbaum</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">10000</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Font>
            <se:LabelPlacement>
              <se:PointPlacement>
                <se:AnchorPoint>
                  <se:AnchorPointX>0</se:AnchorPointX>
                  <se:AnchorPointY>0.5</se:AnchorPointY>
                </se:AnchorPoint>
                <se:Displacement>
                  <se:DisplacementX>3555</se:DisplacementX>
                  <se:DisplacementY>0</se:DisplacementY>
                </se:Displacement>
              </se:PointPlacement>
            </se:LabelPlacement>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:VendorOption name="conflictResolution">false</se:VendorOption>
          </se:TextSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>fclass</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>national_capital</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:TextSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/metre">
            <se:Label>
              <ogc:Function name="strToUpperCase">
                <ogc:PropertyName>name_old</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:Function>
            </se:Label>
            <se:Font>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">Oranienbaum</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">12000</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Font>
            <se:LabelPlacement>
              <se:PointPlacement>
                <se:AnchorPoint>
                  <se:AnchorPointX>0</se:AnchorPointX>
                  <se:AnchorPointY>0.5</se:AnchorPointY>
                </se:AnchorPoint>
              </se:PointPlacement>
            </se:LabelPlacement>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:VendorOption name="underlineText">true</se:VendorOption>
            <se:VendorOption name="conflictResolution">false</se:VendorOption>
          </se:TextSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

I link a sample point lable file, styles and pictures.

[image: QGIS visualization]
[image: GeoServer WRONG visualization of label placements]

[Sample point shapefile - styled. Same style is in SLD above](https://dox.abv.bg/download?id=35498f44f2# - Линк за сваляне)

Answer (score 1):

You need to construct the point you would like the label to appear from your X and Y columns and then tell the [`TextSymbolizer`](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/textsymbolizer.html) to use that geometry to place the label.

I would use something like:

```
<se:TextSymbolizer>
  <se:Geometry>
    <ogc:Function name="geomFromWKT">
      <ogc:Function name="Concatenate">"Point(",ogc:PropertyName(X)," ", ogc:PropertyName(Y),")"</ogc:Function>
    </ogc:Function>
  </se:Geometry>
  <se:Label>
     <ogc:Function name="strToUpperCase">
       <ogc:PropertyName>name_old</ogc:PropertyName>
     </ogc:Function>
   </se:Label>
```

A full list and description of the available functions is [here](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html).

Comment: I am trying from hours now and I struggle with adding this or something similar to this. Maybe because I am trying to fit it in in an already built structure from the paste SLD - 2 - in the initial question. I have all the points constructed as you see. And I am adding the rule between the <TextSymbolizer> as it is written down in the functions/syntax, but I am doing something wrong. I already have the point built. So I tried both ways, and tell the Rule - but I am doing something wrong. Please, can you be a little more precise? I will continue to try of course, I must find a solution for this

Comment: I sometimes use the geometry function as the `label` to check it is being evaluated correctly

Comment: Ok, great news ! It turns out that I did almost the exact same thing! One of the tries!
Bad news is - that I get the same main error of your corrected one:

line 71: cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'ogc:Function' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only. about the
<ogc:Function name="Concatenate">"Point(",ogc:PropertyName(X)," ", ogc:PropertyName(Y),")"</ogc:Function>
I understand from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34493270/element-cannot-have-character-children-because-the-types-content-type-is-ele THAT it is a special character issue..

Comment: You can (probably) ignore that if it is a validation error - see if it works anyway

Comment: I tried of course, but It did not work. I even tried several other things, but it still does not work. The labels do not appear. I added things like the parts of initial code: <se:Font>, <se:Fill>, does not work. With or without them.
Current state of the cities that I can not visualize: http://prntscr.com/wlwldv
Again, even with the other older options for Font, Fill and so on - it does not visualize it.

Comment: Hello again, Ian. For such a long time now I tried a lot of different things. But the code that you gave above does not work. No matter what I changed.
Does it work for you? If you try it with a layer, with manually positioned labels? Like in the pictures I gave?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution! It is a bit long to explain, but here is the short explanation.

First, I needed to change the structure of the data/architecture - so I created another field in the attribute table - a new field was created ("geom1"), which combines the coordinate of the 2 fields and adds POINT.(it is text, not double like the previous 2 fields with coordinates)

It takes the text field with coordinates, however - if they are NULL (empty, those, that are not moved manually do not have coordinates in the X and Y fields) - the code does not work, so there is a function that gets one of the 2 fields.

```
        <se:Geometry>
          <ogc:Function name="geomFromWKT">
            <ogc:Function name="if_then_else">
                <ogc:Function name="isNull">
                    <ogc:PropertyName>geom1</ogc:PropertyName>
                </ogc:Function>
                <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>   
                <ogc:PropertyName>geom1</ogc:PropertyName>
            </ogc:Function>
          </ogc:Function>
        </se:Geometry>
```